# How to install Python packages under Linux environment?

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev

Recently I am using the virtual machine to do the Python coding. The system is under Linux, which means I have to use Command Lines to install the Python packages. I am familiar with Anaconda to do Python coding at school. But in the real working environment, to save money, I have to use Linux.

Now I have a problem in installing the Python packages. Like I used to use pip to install, now I have to use Sudo. There is some information about how to install from the website, for

```
$ sudo apt install Python-pandas
```

But I don't know how to install the class. 
For example, I would like to conduct a linear regression analysis. I installed the sklearn successfully.

```
$ sudo apt install python-sklearn
```

How can I install sklearn.linear_model and import LinearRegression
and how to import train_test_split from sklearn.corss_validation?

Can I do it in eclipse? Or the only way is to install in Linux. 
Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean by "install sklearn.linear_model"? What makes you think you need to install that? Why don't you just keep using anaconda and pip?

Comment: Because of the cost of windows is much more expensive.

Comment: I said anaconda and pip, not windows.

Comment: The package name is `python-pandas`, not **P**ython-pandas. .... Use `apt-cache search [name]` to decide package name. Or use on-line search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pandas&searchon=names

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can install anaconda in linux
2. the package includes all of the classes
3. sudo is all lower case
4. you can still use `sudo pip install` or `pip install --user`